# JQuery .on() isn't binding click events to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a textbox that dynamically adds an element when I press enter, and another that deletes the element when I click the delete button. The delete method works for any existing elements, but doesn't work for any elements that were dynamically inserted.

Here's the code:

```
$ ->
    # AJAX to add a new stock
    $("#add-symbol").keypress (e) ->
        if e.which == 13
            url = $(this).data('url')
            name = $(this).val()
            $.ajax
                url: url
                type: "POST"
                data: {
                    user_id: $('#info').data('user-id'),
                    name: name
                }
                success: (response) ->
                    if response.status == 200
                        new_element = '<a class="item" data-path="' + response.path + '" data-stock="' + response.symbol + '">'+ response.symbol + '<i class="icon remove"></i></a>'
                        $('#symbols').append(new_element)
                        $('#add-symbol').val('')
                    else
                     #deal with errors

    # AJAX to delete stocks
    $('.icon.remove').on('click', (e) ->
        console.log('click click')
        $parent = $($(this).parent().get(0))
        stock = $parent.data('stock')
        user_id = $("#info").data('user-id')
        url = $parent.data('path')

        $.ajax
            url: url
            type: "DELETE"
            data: {
                user_id: user_id,
                name: stock
            }
            success: (response) ->
                if response.status == 200
                    $parent.remove()
                else
                    # deal with errors
    )
```

Any ideas? From what I've read, .on() should fix the issue of binding a click event to a dynamically generated element, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: `on` should fix the issue if used propely i.e use it with event delegation syntax. `$(container).on('çlick', '.icon.remove', function(){...` Where container is the container selector that holds these elements and are available any time.

Comment: @PSL Tried that as well, no dice

Comment: @PSL Never mind, I messed up my container before. That works perfectly. Cheers!

Comment: Tell me your syntax doesn't really look like that!

Comment: @PHPglue What do you mean?

Comment: `->` instead of `{`. Missing commas inside Objects. No `()` around condition. Multiple statements after bad condition before else condition using no curly braces. If this is really your code and it does anything it's a miracle.

Comment: @PHPglue Oops, I should mention that it's coffeescript

Comment: Yeah, that would help. I don't know coffeescript.

Answer (score 61):

this is wrong: `$('.icon.remove').on('click'...`

this is right: `$(document).on('click', '.icon.remove', function)`

you can use any **container** instead of document (which is the most highlevel container).

Comment: Rightly Answered. :-)

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. Although I'm yet to figure out what the difference is. [The jQuery site](http://api.jquery.com/on/) clearly says the former is a correct usage of the binding..

Comment: Thanks time saver, i always forget how to do it correctly and shortly.

Comment: @army The former syntax never works regardless of the documentation.  It's just something you have to know. :)

Comment: FYI. $('.icon.remove').on('click'... works for static html elements
(http://api.jquery.com/on/)