# remove() is working on only first div not on rest dynamically added fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove the HTML field but remove is not working on dynamically added fields.

```
 $('.delete-ques').on('click', function() { 
            alert('hello');
            $(this).parent().remove(); 
            return false;
            });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gp2gwana/3/

Try to add div and remove

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371141/jquery-on-isnt-binding-click-events-to-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/gp2gwana/4/. Use event delegation technique for attaching events to dynamically created DOM element.

Comment: `$('#clone-ques').on('click','.delete-ques', function() { `

Answer (score 3):

You need event delegation for attaching events to dynamically added elements:

```
$('#clone-ques').on('click','.delete-ques', function() { 
        alert('hello');
        $(this).parent().remove(); 
        return false;
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qo9ccw74/)**

Answer (score 2):

do this

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete-ques', function() {
    // do something
});
```

You will find some good example

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements) and [here](http://codepedia.info/click-event-for-dynamic-button-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

Use document.on click event for delete on dynamically added elements:

**.on** used for single handler for all elements that match your selector, including the ones created dynamically.

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/7s05cdoy/

```
$(document).on('click','.delete-ques',function() {
      $(this).closest('.parent-question').remove();  // using closest you can get parent of this link
      return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may used $(doument)

```
$(document).on('click','.delete-ques', function() { 
            alert('hello');
            $(this).parent().remove(); 
            return false;
 });
```

Your working code https://jsfiddle.net/gp2gwana/5/

Comment: `Document` should be `document`

Comment: @MilindAnantwar working fine with `Document` Please check jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Everything is perfect in your code. except below line

```
$('#select-question'+i).selectize({create: true});
```

Try your existing code by commenting above line of code.

I seen an error in console

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectize is not a function`

**Edit**

You should below line of code before return false inside

```
$('.delete-ques').on('click', function() { 
        $(this).parent().remove(); 
        return false;
});
```

Try updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gp2gwana/6/)